# AWS APIGateway Integration Response Mapping Templates do not switch correctly based on Content-Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, integration

I am experimenting with an AWS API-Gateway integration with an S3 backend. I have noticed the switch between different mapping-templates in the integration-response does not appear to work.

In integration-response, I have the following mapping templates:

**application/json:**

```
{
  type: "JSON",
  body: "$input.body"
}
```

**text/plain:**

```
PlainText:
$input.body
```

Nothing I can do appears to be able to make the `text/plain` mapping template to be used - it always uses `application/json`.

I would expect that the `text/plain` mapping template to be used based on one of the following being true:

1. S3 returns content with `Content-Type: text/plain`.
2. The initial request to API-Gateway passes an `Accept: text/plain` header.

As per the example below, S3 returns a `Content-Type: text/plain` AND I request with `Accept: text/plain`. API-Gateway correctly responds with `Content-Type: text/plain` also.
However the `application/json` template is still used to transform the body.

I have even removed `application/json` as a valid response type from the method-response entirely, but still nothing.

Any thoughts why this is happening?

*FYI I am using a classic v1 ApiGateway (Rest).*

```
Execution log for request c24cfce3-2cf3-4693-ad72-4fdf44f4fdcd
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Starting execution for request: c24cfce3-2cf3-4693-ad72-4fdf44f4fdcd
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /feeds-poc/test.txt
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Method request path: {filename=test.txt}
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Method request query string: {}
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Method request headers: {Accept=text/plain}
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Method request body before transformations: 
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request URI: https://my-bucket-id.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test.txt
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request headers: {Authorization=****57173a, X-Amz-Date=20210519T171338Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=123456789a, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_123456789a, X-Amz-Security-Token=**** [TRUNCATED]
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Sending request to https://my-bucket-id.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test.txt
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 43 ms
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response headers: {x-amz-id-2=****, x-amz-request-id=****, Date=Wed, 19 May 2021 17:13:39 GMT, Last-Modified=Mon, 17 May 2021 16:45:13 GMT, ETag="420f804aa21220bf0db57bb4b9799c8a", Accept-Ranges=bytes, Content-Type=text/plain, Content-Length=13, Server=AmazonS3}
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response body before transformations: It's working

Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Method response body after transformations: {
  type: "JSON",
  body: "It's working
"
}
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=****, Content-Type=text/plain}
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Successfully completed execution
Wed May 19 17:13:38 UTC 2021 : Method completed with status: 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Support confirmed to me that the switch is based on the original request `Accept` header. Testing this using Postman confirms this functionality.

The test tools built into the AWS console for API-Gateway however do not appear to cater for testing response mapping templates - from AWS support: `the purpose of API Gateway test console is only to test the Integration, it doesn't work for end-to-end request`.